# How does Circu, Dimir Lobotomist interact with defeated players in a Free for All?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-multiplayer

Could an opponent cast a card with the same name as a card exiled by [Circu, Dimir Lobotomist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCircu%2c%20Dimir%20Lobotomist%5d) after you defeat the owner of the card in a Free for All?

Comment: @Glorfindel I think your edit changed the direction of the question. My reading of the original wording was that they were asking about Circu's controller losing the game.

Comment: That's a possibility but I cannot imagine that situation would lead to confusion.

Comment: Hmm, either it could easily be either... while searching for an answer to my related question; I found a few people on other forums asking if you can cast cards after Circu goes away.

Comment: Nit: You say "under the effect", but the exiled cards are not subject to any effect. You meant "exiled by".

Comment: Nit: Exiled cards have no controller. You meant "owner".

Comment: @ChrisSheib since it's not 100% clear what situation you were referring to, I've answered both of them; please indicate if the current version of the question is what you meant to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is some confusion about the original wording of the question, let's first assume you control [Circu, Dimir Lobotomist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCircu%2c%20Dimir%20Lobotomist%5d), used it to exile a couple of spells from an opponent's library and that opponent is now defeated.

> 800.4a When a player leaves the game, all objects (see rule 109) owned by that player leave the game ...

The exiled cards owned by the defeated player leave the game, and don't count for Circu's ability anymore:

> 607.2a If an object has an activated or triggered ability printed on it that instructs a player to exile one or more cards and an ability printed on it that refers either to "the exiled cards" or to cards "exiled with [this object]," these abilities are linked. The second ability refers only to cards in the exile zone that were put there as a result of an instruction to exile them in the first ability.

Your other opponents can cast those spells again (unless you've also exiled said card from a library of an opponent who is still in the game).

---

If you meant to ask what happens when an opponent controlling Circu, Dimir Lobotomist is defeated; the exiled cards stay exiled, but Circu's static ability stops functioning: it's no longer on the battlefield, and you (and other opponents) can cast spells with the same name as the exiled cards once again.

Comment: It's not clear to me from the wording on Circu that it would not apply to cards that had been exiled but no longer exist. The same question could be asked about a card that was un-exiled (Runic Repetition, Eldrazi Processors, etc). If a card is moved from exile, does it no longer count as "a card exiled with Circu"?

Comment: It would probably be worth quoting rule 607.2a to address that. The part relevant to GendoIkari's question says "The second ability refers only to **cards in the exile zone** that were put there as a result of an instruction to exile them in the first ability."

Comment: @murgatroid99, thanks! I really couldn't figure out which way that one would go; in plain English either interpretation would be valid.

Comment: If the person controlling circu is defeated all card that were under it's effect can be played